# Динамическое добавление субдоменов

Tags: yii2, apache, поддомены

Задача состоит в том, что б для каждого зарегистрированого юзера создавался свой поддомен. Наприме, site.com должен быть для даного юзера user.site.com, и так для каждого юзера свой поддомен. Читал что это можно реализовать через сервис cloudflare. Сайт работает на Yii2. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Сайт работает на Yii2. Как это можно реализовать?

"что б для каждого зарегистрированого юзера создавался свой поддомен" - не важно на каком фреймворке построен сайт. cloudflare тем более не причем.

Для возможности использования поддоменов в движке (на сайте) - прежде всего нужно на сервере прописывать алиасы (ServerAlias) на каждого юзера или же сразу wilkard-домены сделать.

Для апача:
`ServerAlias *.site.com`

Comment: Пасибо, да ServerAlias сработал.

Comment: А на хостинге просто добавить поддомен *.site.com? или там какие то сложности могут возникнуть, панель управления cPanel, хостинг coretek.ru

Comment: С cPanel-ью пользователь ничего сделать не сможет (во всяком случае сколько я их видел - нигде нельзя было). Это нужно к хостеру обращаться (и то если он согласятся). В ISP с этим просто - галочка в панели.

Comment: На хостинге работает, путем добавления суддомена *.site.com, и ненада лезть в настройки apache.